# Connecting LinkedIn API via Azure Data Factory REST API Linked Service

Tags: azure-data-factory, linkedin-api

How can I successfully use the REST API endpoint in Azure Data Factory to connect to LinkedIn API?

I am facing an issue where I try using the REST API in Azure Data Factory and try the 'OAuth2ClientCredential' (See Linked Service in ADF below):

[image]

Base URL = https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

Token Endpoint = https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

Scope = r_ads,r_ads_reporting,r_basicprofile

I have disabled Server Certification Validation and I receive the below error:

Error Code: 20150

Details: Failed to get access token from your token endpoint. Error returned from your authorization server: {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This application is not allowed to create application tokens"}
Processed Http request failed.

Is there a field inside the Linked Service that I am neglecting to fill out to utilize the REST API to connect LinkedIn API to ADF?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Client Id which you are using is not authorized. Or you can consider using web activity to make API call and get token and once we get token pass that to subsequent activities.
Kindly check below link if that helps to get access to linkedIn API.

Comment: Hello, I sent this request over to Microsoft & ADF does not currently support 3-legged OAuth (only 2-legged). Will keep this post open until they are able to put in an enhancement for this feature. Thanks!